# Forward Bounce Notifications for Undeliverable SES Messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I would like to be able to forward the email address for the recipient of a bounced email from SES to another endpoint for further processing. 
My thoughts so far on this matter are setting up the typical SNS topic for bounce notifications, and have a lambda triggered on a bounced email. 
The recipient data can be grabbed from the SNS message directly, so the event parameter can be parsed and the lambda can send an email via SES notifying a team that an email was bounced and specific remediation actions are necessary.

Essentially I would just like to notify a team that an account should be removed if the user in question cannot be reached (i.e, the user does not exist in our own systems, but still exists in AWS).

I'm not sure if anyone's done this before or has any thoughts I haven't come up with, I'm open to anything as I add this piece to my current automation.

Comment: Have you read this documentation? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sns-ses-dynamodb/
It helped for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy and you have kind of already provided the solution. 
Below are two ways:

1. Configure a SNS topic for your SES to send an email to a recepient you want. You dont need lambda for it. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html#configure-feedback-notifications-console).
   Drawback: For every bounced email, the recepient you configure in the SNS will receive an email. It might or might not suite your requirement , depending upon the bounce rate.
   Also you might not like the content of the email sent. Its a json format.
2. The Other solution I used was: Configure a SNS topic for SES to send a notification in the SQS queue.(not an email) This notification is json object which contains the destination email address on which the email bounced as well if it was a Hard bounce or a soft bounce. A hard bounce is a one in which the recipient email address do not exist. A soft bounce is caused by some temporary network issue, large email content etc. which can be resolved manually or by automatic retries.
   Then run a small python code to pull the messages from the SQS queue and find out the email addresses. 
   I ran this script to get the list of email addresses once in a while and shared with the IT team to remove the accounts.

```
max_queue_messages = 10
message_bodies = []
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='SES-Email-Bounce')

while True:
    messages_to_delete = []
    for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=max_queue_messages):
        data = json.loads(message.body)
        data1 = json.loads(data['Message'])
        data2 = data1['mail']
        data3 = data2['destination']
        data4 = ''.join(data3)
        print(data4)
        with open('invaild_emails.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(data4.lstrip('[\'').rstrip('\']') + "\n")
            file.close()
        # add message to delete
        messages_to_delete.append({
            'Id': message.message_id,
            'ReceiptHandle': message.receipt_handle
            })
            # message.delete()

        # if you don't receive any notifications the
        # messages_to_delete list will be empty
    if len(messages_to_delete) == 0:
        break
        # delete messages to remove them from SQS queue
        # handle any errors
    else:
        delete_response = queue.delete_messages(
            Entries=messages_to_delete)
```